# Does crashing during a test mean you have to scrap the roller coaster?

Tags: rollercoaster-tycoon

If I'm testing a roller coaster design and it crashes, will I need to scrap it, like you have to when a finished, running coaster crashes? To put it another way, in the eyes of the game/guests is a roller coaster that crashes during testing different from a coaster crashing "Open"?

Comment: Are we definitely talking about the first RCT game?

Answer (score 11):

Let's do some science to find out! Here's what I did: I created a new coaster specifically designed to crash. Upon testing, of course, it crashes. When I open it up, nobody wants to ride it because it "isn't safe" (note that if I didn't test it, someone probably would have gotten on).

From there, I made all of the changes necessary to make sure it didn't crash ever again, tested it, and re-opened it. To my surprise, the guests were still convinced the ride was not safe, even though it wasn't designed to blow up this time. From this result, we can conclude that **yes**, crashes during testing *do*, in fact, matter. But there are a couple of ways to prevent them, or fix the problem after-the-fact if needed.

If you suspect your coaster *might* crash during testing, hold your mouse over the "close" button, and watch closely, especially in the section you're concerned with. If it starts to fly off the track, double click the "close" button to stop it. If you're quick enough, you'll close and reset the ride before it starts actually crashing (it doesn't count if things haven't exploded).

If you *aren't* fast enough, and your design is strictly above-ground, you can save that design, remove the whole thing, and replace it. That way, you won't have to start *all* over.

If your track *did* have some underground sections, then it gets complicated, since when you place a saved track, it tries to put the lowest point *on* the ground. At that point, it might be best to start over.

Comment: Did you attempt to delete the station platform to mitigate the problem?  I dont have access to rct at the moment, but i imagine deleting the station platform, pressing test, getting error cause no platform, then readd it may do somrthing

Comment: @eyeofthehawks I'll try it, but I doubt this will fix things, given guest's behavior upon other construction. It's possible though.

Comment: It depends on what the game defines on THAT coaster.  Its very likely the entire ride must be deleted, but workarounds are possible depending how the game was designed

Answer (score -3):

Yes, At least in RCT3. If the coaster crashes in build mode, it wont have an impact on the guests.

Comment: The difference being that in RCT3 in build mode when you are testing it, it's just a ghost of the coaster and not the actual thing.  If you test in RCT1/2 or 3 out of build mode it runs with the actual train

Comment: RCT3 != RCT1. This doesn't really apply here